# Install ROS and Gazebo on MacOS 14

Tags: ros, gazebo, macos

I am a newbie in robotics. Now I am trying to install ROS and Gazebo on MacOS 14, but it is quite confusing for a newbie like me. Can you guys create a post on how to install Ros and Gazebo on MacOS 14 to help me. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Although MacOS installations aren't my strong suit, I'd suggest checking out RobotStack. It's a relatively new tool that simplifies the installation of various ROS versions across different operating systems. I'd suggest starting with ROS2 Humble.

**Here are the steps:** https://robostack.github.io/index.html

If anyone here knows better, give a shout if RobotStack isn't the way to go!